# While publishing the Asp.Net project the project has completely collapsed

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012

While working on an Asp.Net project. Firstly, I added a **WCF service project** to the solution and a **Global.asax** file which has a timer method that sending an e-mail **per minutes**

When i came to deployment process so i clicked to publish button on the visual studio solution explorer it has gave me an exception before and closed the visual studio and reopen it but all project items has gone even static files like css files.

I have searched all directories. I looked for a restore points but there i could not seen anything in D driver related the project.i don't understand.

I think this is a bug and i have shared for making better for all

Comment: revert source control?

Comment: i haven't a source control. code is just in my notebook. i think this is a bug of the visual studio.

Comment: @HamitYıldırım - if you have 10 years of experience in software development, you should know that source control is your #1 priority for any development. always.  I would hope you now understand this.  Having said that, my guess is that you tried to publish to the same directory you were publishing from, and when an error occurred, it deleted the destination, which was also your source.  So, two times user error.